# Is it possible to run automatically celery at startup?

Tags: django, celery

I have python server based on django and celery. 
Each time computer restarts, apache2 starts so my server is working, BUT I have to restart celery manually (going to my project directory and executing "python manage.py celeryd"). What is the correct solution for production? I mean, is there a possibility to start celery as daemon?

Here http://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/contrib/debian/init.d/ I found two scripts which looks like they should be in /etc/init.d/ like apache2 script that starts apache2. But I put them to /etc/init.d/ and as I see nothing changes.

Comment: ask the it guys at serverfault.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should take a look at http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian

In short, with the `celeryd` script in `/etc/init.d`:

```
$ update-rc.d celeryd defaults
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/celeryd ...
    /etc/rc0.d/K20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
    /etc/rc1.d/K20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
    /etc/rc6.d/K20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
    /etc/rc2.d/S20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
    /etc/rc3.d/S20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
    /etc/rc4.d/S20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
    /etc/rc5.d/S20celeryd -> ../init.d/celeryd
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, what about celerybeat? Do I need to update-rc.d it too?

Comment: Yes! remember to only run one instance of it though!

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm to me! Unfortunately, I spent a lot of time to find out what did I do wrong (forgot to chmod 755 both scripts), but finally everything is working! Thanks for your help, asksol!

Comment: This work with celeryd for me, but almost same don't work with auto startup celeryd-multi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196555/celeryd-multi-as-cron-at-startup

Comment: Hmmm.. I did this, got that same output listed, and rebooted.  When I check the processes, there are none.  And /etc/init.d/celeryd status returns `celeryd is stopped`.  I tried to run update-rc.d celeryd defaults again and it said there was already an entry.  Any idea why it's not being started?

Comment: I see.... on ubuntu /var/run is tmpfs in memory, so it disappears on boot.... http://askubuntu.com/questions/89352/does-ubuntu-periodically-clean-empty-directories-under-var-run

Comment: added `CREATE_CELERY_DIRS=1` to my /etc/default/celeryd config.

Comment: Should the `update-rc.d ... enable` command also be run as described here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/388434/celeryd-not-running-at-startup